# PostgreSQL: is CREATE INDEX faster for new indexes if a clustered index already exists?

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, indexing

My question is about performance during the data loading process. I need to create four indexes on a 1.6 billion rows table and I was wondering which one of the following is faster:

1. creating an index, clustering it and then creating the other indexes:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX i_col1 ON db.tbl USING btree (col1);
   CLUSTER db.tbl USING i_col1;
   CREATE INDEX i_col2 ON db.tbl USING btree (col2);
   CREATE INDEX i_col3 ON db.tbl USING btree (col3);
   CREATE INDEX i_col4 ON db.tbl USING btree (col4);
   ```
2. creating all the indexes and then clustering the same first index:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX i_col1 ON db.tbl USING btree (col1);
   CREATE INDEX i_col2 ON db.tbl USING btree (col2);
   CREATE INDEX i_col3 ON db.tbl USING btree (col3);
   CREATE INDEX i_col4 ON db.tbl USING btree (col4);
   CLUSTER db.tbl USING i_col1;
   ```

Comment: What happens when you benchmark them?

Comment: Benchmark means deleting already existing indexes and loosing days of processing. The only thing I can do is doing some tests on a smaller table, but I don't know if it's really comparable.

Comment: Doing development against the production environment?  Not exactly enviable.

Comment: Not properly..development and production envs must have the same data and I'm just looking for the right sequence of operations in the data-loading process. This question is related to a small part of it. One thing I would like to know is, for example, if it's better doing VACUUM ANALYZE before or after a CREATE INDEX. But that's another question :)

Comment: It should be OK if development lags a few days behind production, unless you're doing something really weird.  The whole point of having a development environment is so you can safely corrupt its data or otherwise "mess with" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index works like... an index! Think of an index of a book, which specifies the contents of its pages. So the index will point out to Postgres where that specific data is on the disk.

When you perform a CLUSTER operation, Postgres will **physically reorganize** the data in the disk.

So, based on that information, the option 1 is the fastest. See, if you cluster the data before creating the 3 remaining indexes, the data will be closer to each other in the disk, which will make it easier to Postgres to find the data it needs, which will make the index creation faster.

BUT, reserve some time to think if you **really** need all those indexes in the same table. Too much indexes can be worse than having no indexes at all. Quoting [Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createindex.html):

> *Indexes are primarily used to enhance database performance (though*
>   *inappropriate use can result in slower performance).*

Additionally, I shouldn't be answering your VACUUM question, because that's not what this topic is about, but it is better if you perform the VACUUM before the CREATE INDEX, because the VACUUM removes all the dead tuples, therefore, you'll have less trash to iterate over when creating the index. Take a look at [this link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-vacuum.html) for more info on VACUUM process.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Indexes are a HUGE improvement over performance, but they take a lot of space on disk. If you have the right amount of free space, RAM and the right postgres configuration, then indexes make the difference even when you have tens of them. Performance degradation is more likely to happen over multiple indexes or with hundreds of indexes on the same table based on the most used queries.